# How to create an Excel File with javascript?

Tags: javascript, excel, blob

I would like to know if it is possible to create an Excel File and make it downloaded from a web page with javascript ?

Currentlly, I succes to create a .csv and make it downloaded with the following code :

```
var blob = new Blob([csvText], { type: 'text/csv;charset=UFT-8;' });
var link = document.createElement("a");
if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
    // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.setAttribute("href", url);
    link.setAttribute("download", "file.csv");
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

I am wondering if there is any librairies in javascript with permit to convert the file from csv format to xlsx format and make it downloaded the same way than the csv ?

The final aim is to set a template in the downlaoded xlsx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is couple of options
https://github.com/stephenliberty/excel-builder.js

Another github project with less Excel options but less worries about Excel compatibility issues can be found here: ExcellentExport.js
https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport

Answer (score 1):

yeas it is possible you can use sheetJS to create xlsx file use following java script code

```
      var ns = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      ns.props = {
        title: "new excell sheet",
        subject: "test",
        Ather: "Shan",
        createdDate: Date.now(),
      };
      ns.SheetNames.push("Test");
      var nb_data = [["hello", "shan"]];
      var nb = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(nb_data);
      ns.Sheets["Test"] = nb;

      var nbOut = XLSX.write(ns, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "binary" });
```

to save your file use following function  as the parameter s you need to pass nbOut variable

```
      function saveBook(s) {
        var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
        for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
          view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
        }
        return buf;
      }

      $("#create_sheet").click(function () {
        saveAs(
          new Blob([saveBook(nbOut)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }),
          "test.xlsx"
        );
      });
```

you can find sheet library from [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs)!

And you can find FileSaver.js library from [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)!

Answer (score 0):

found two useful JavaScript libraries to create xls files using JavaScript

A simple and lightweight one

https://github.com/egeriis/zipcelx

An more featured library

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs