# How can I export array data into excel? (Array has JSON data)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, excel

I have been looking for a solution on how to do this for a long time now.

**Explanation:**

What I am trying to accomplish is to get the data from an array (that is from a json file) and export it into excel.

**What I have done:**

```
function exportToExel(exelExportData) {
  var CsvString = "";
  exelExportData.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ',';
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(CsvString);
  var x = document.createElement("A");
  x.setAttribute("href", CsvString );
  x.setAttribute("download","somedata.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.click();
}
```

I got this code from some other post and it worked pretty well, but when i tried to replace the data with my data (exelExportData) it did not work.

**What the array data looks like:**

[image: The array logged into the console]

As you can see, it is built like a JSON-file.

**What I get when I try to export to excel:**

[image: Excel output]

(Basically, something wrong)

**What I need it to look like:**

[image: What i need]

This is a lot of text in this message, but I have been trying to figure this out for ages. Please, if you have the knowledge to help me, do me a favor and help me.

I do not mind if you make a new function, any help is much appreciated. Please understand that I am new to JavaScript and need easy explanation as well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can [import a JSON file into Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-data-sources-power-query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) directly. If that doesn't work for you, please explain why.

Comment: Could you just export it to JSON, and use Get Data > From File > From JSON to import it? https://www.howtogeek.com/775651/how-to-convert-a-json-file-to-microsoft-excel/

Comment: If you're looking to use javascript to directly create an Excel file, see related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327435.  I have personally used [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) and it is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Hi @LukePersola, i am sorry if there is a misunderstanding, but what i am trying to achive is the array data to be able to be exported into excel. NOT the json data.

Answer (score 0):

Good Morning,
Note: We use spreading (...) and map to recreate a string array with a header (your fields for the excel file)
Hoping it works
Note bis: I only rewrote the algorithm for transforming the json into an excel file Note that it would also be possible to use libraries

```
const exelExportData = [
    {toto: 'toto', tutu: 'tutu', tata: 'tata'},
    {toto: 'toto', tutu: 'tutu', tata: 'tata'},
    {toto: 'toto', tutu: 'tutu', tata: 'tata'},
    {toto: 'toto', tutu: 'tutu', tata: 'tata'},
]

const items = exelExportData // your json data 
const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? 'unknownData' : value  // handle null data or actual value 
const header = Object.keys(items[0]) // get your headers  -> toto,tutu,tata
const csv = [
  header.join(','),
  ...items.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','))
].join('\r\n')

console.log(csv)

NOTE: 

spreading  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
map : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it is supposed to not make a excel file? I am trying to use your code, but there is no excel file being made for the user.